# ベジータが家族旅行! is 旅行 here a verb or a noun?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, nouns

I found this phrase

> 約束リゾートへ! ベジータが家族旅行!

translated as

> Vegeta Goes on a Family Trip?!

I was wondering if here 旅行 is a verb or a noun. Is the literal translation of this phrase "Vegeta goes on a family trip?" and the "goes" is assumed, is "Vegeta (and) family travels?" or is the literal translation something different to the former options?

Comment: 旅行SURU (SURU is omitted)  __________ called 体言止め   https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101019183959AAgryhp  That's a headline.   Also in English > Because space is limited, headlines are written in a compressed telegraphic style, using special syntactic conventions: Forms of the verb "to be" are omitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Titles (and advertisements) often employ 体言止め, i.e. ending a sentence with a noun. The rules are flexible, but often the 体言 can be understood as the noun of a する-verb and the almost superfluous する is omitted.

> オバマが来日

In ベジータが家族旅行, 旅行する is a common する-verb, and 家族旅行をする and 家族旅行する are all about equally common (130→485, 116→478 in Google results). In any case, less important than determining which verb could have been omitted in 体言止め is that the sentence is clear without any verb.

Comment: [  家族旅行する ]  is very common on the net.

Comment: @H.Ha You're right. The version をする seems to be only slightly more common. I checked also 修学旅行, 新婚旅行, 慰安旅行 and it was the same for all of these.